# Remove shadow from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, calayer, uibezierpath

I show shadow using the following code.

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(317, 0, 1, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height)];
        self.navigationController.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 0);  /*Change value of X n Y as per your need of shadow to appear to like right bottom or left bottom or so on*/
        self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
        self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

I want to remove this shadow.I have tried some thing but not working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by replacing balckColor to clearColor and Opacity to 0.0

```
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you not just set opacity to 0.0.

```
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

Thanks!!